# Good textbook for an intro to geometry and topology?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, education

I'm teaching a Master's level course called "Basic Concepts in Topology and Geometry". The listed topics are:

- Topological manifolds. The fundamental group and covering spaces. Applications.
- Singular homology and applications.
- Smooth manifolds. Differential forms and Stokes’ theorem, definition of de-Rham cohomology.

Does anyone have experience teaching a course like this and have recommendations for a good textbook to use? I'd especially love a textbook that I can refer back to as the main source for our material even if I don't cover everything in class. (Or where I can make the content of the course be a certain set of chapters).

Loring Tu's book seems nice but too big for a one-semester course. Ballmann's book seems nice (though I'd need to supplement it with something about singular homology). John Lee's book seems good, but it doesn't cover differentiable manifolds.

Comment: I'm a student, not a teacher, but I used Tu's book to self-study manifolds and I think it should be possible to cover all the (important) material within a semester. For example, the material on Lie groups and algebras could easily be left out. 
John Lee has two (presently relevant) books: one on topological manifolds, one on smooth manifolds. The two of them combined will most certainly provide you with all the reference material that you need.

Comment: I might say that these are not basic concepts of topology. They are, perhaps, basic concepts of algebraic and differential topology, but “basic concepts of topology” evokes a first course in general topology such as reading (the first few chapters of) Munkres.

Comment: Milnor's *Topology from the differentiable viewpoint* is a nice, short introduction.

Comment: What books have your colleagues used in teaching this course in past years?

Comment: Lee's book on smooth manifolds does cover at least the first and third bullet points.